# Images showing in wrong places

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to make a very simple tiled rpg. In the first tests, tiles where in the correct places, but when I refactored the program and created classes called map and tile.map for storing and displaying maps and tile for storing tile's pos and img and for collision detection, it was mis-placing the images.

The class's structure includes a Main class "Frame" that holds the map stored in string array, then makes a map class and puts the string array, grass and water textures,also the tile Height and Width and the Graphics object (the init is called inside the paint method soo i will get an graphics object not a null).

The map makes an 2d array made out of tile classes which is based on the string array. The tile gets the graphics object and draws the img on to it. Now when I run it it puts the tiles in wrong location.

Links to the code:

1. (main class) Frame : [pastebin.com/dephCtfg](http://pastebin.com/dephCtfg)
2. Map : [pastebin.com/hKitArsf](http://pastebin.com/hKitArsf)
3. Tile : [pastebin.com/aagDjEWp](http://pastebin.com/aagDjEWp)

**Edit:** Added whole code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class UsersFrame extends JFrame {
   // images
   private Image imgs[] = new Image[2];
   private int tileH = 25;
   private int tileW = 25;
   // map1
   private Map map1;
   String map1St[] = { 
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0111111110011111111000000",
         "0111111110011111111000000",
         "0111111110011111111000000",
         "0111000110011100011000000",
         "0110000110011000011000000",
         "0111001110011100111000000",
         "0111101110011110111000000",
         "0111111110011111111000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000001000000000000000",
         "0000000010000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000", };

   public UsersFrame() {
      loadPics();
   }

   public void paint(Graphics gg) {
      map1 = new Map(map1St, tileW, tileH, imgs, gg);
      map1.drawMap();
   }

   public static void main(String s[]) {
      JFrame frame = new UsersFrame();
      frame.setTitle("RPG");
      // Add a window listner for close button
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      // This is an empty content area in the frame
      JLabel jlbempty = new JLabel("");
      jlbempty.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 625));
      frame.getContentPane().add(jlbempty, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   private void loadPics() {
      Image grass = new ImageIcon("/Users/olek/RESOURCES/RPG/grass.jpg")
            .getImage();
      Image water = new ImageIcon("/Users/olek/RESOURCES/RPG/water.jpg")
            .getImage();
      imgs[0] = grass;
      imgs[1] = water;
   }
}

class Map {
   // TODO: fix images not showing
   // position
   private int dx = 0;
   private int dy = 0;
   // position on the frame
   private int tx = 0;
   private int ty = 0;
   private int tileH;
   private int tileW;
   private int mapW = 25;
   private int mapH = 25;
   private Image imgs[] = { null, null };
   private Graphics g;
   Tile map[][] = new Tile[mapW][mapH];
   String mapSt[];
   private boolean doneDrawing = false;

   public Map(String mapSt[], int tileW, int tileH, Image imgs[], Graphics g) {
      this.mapSt = mapSt;
      this.tileW = tileW;
      this.tileH = tileH;
      dx = 0;
      dy = 0;
      tx = 0;
      ty = 0;
      this.imgs = imgs;
      doneDrawing = false;
      this.g = g;
      System.out.print(g.toString());
   }

   public void drawMap() {
      if (g == null) {
         System.out.print("g is null");
         return;
      }
      char currTile = mapSt[dy].charAt(dx);
      System.out.print(currTile + "\n");
      if (currTile == '0') {
         System.out.print("drawing water at " + tx + " , " + ty + "\n");
         map[dx][dy] = new Tile(imgs[1], tileW, tileH, tx, ty, true, false, g);
      }
      if (currTile == '1') {
         System.out.print("drawing grass at " + tx + " , " + ty + "\n");
         map[dx][dy] = new Tile(imgs[0], tileH, tileH, tx, ty, false, false, g);
      }
      calcPlacePos();
      if (!doneDrawing) {
         drawMap();
      }
   }

   private void calcPlacePos() {
      if (dx != (mapW - 1)) {
         // System.out.print(dx+" != ("+mapW+"-1)\n");
         dx++;
      }
      // System.out.print(dx+" == ("+mapW+"-1) && "+dy+" != ("+mapH+"-1)\n");
      if (dx == (mapW - 1) && dy != (mapH - 1)) {
         dx = 0;
         dy++;
      }
      if (dx == (mapW - 1) && dy == (mapH - 1)) {
         doneDrawing = true;
         System.out.print("done");
      }
      tx = dx * tileW;
      ty = dy * tileH;
   }
}

class Tile {
   private Image img;
   private int tileH;
   private int tileW;
   private int posX;
   private int posY;
   private boolean isWall;
   private boolean front;
   private Graphics gr;

   public Tile(Image i, int w, int h, int pX, int pY, boolean wall,
         boolean inFront, Graphics g) {
      img = i;
      tileH = h;
      tileW = w;
      posX = pX;
      posY = pY;
      isWall = wall;
      front = inFront;
      gr = g;
      drawTile();
   }

   public boolean isWall() {
      return isWall;
   }

   public boolean isInFront() {
      return front;
   }

   public Image getImage() {
      return img;
   }

   public void setImage(Image i) {
      if (i != null) {
         img = i;
      } else {
         System.out.print("Could not assign image to Tile object becouse \n" +
                " gotten image is null");
      }
   }

   private void drawTile() {
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) gr;
      g2d.translate(0, 22);
      g2d.drawImage(img, posX, posX, null);
      System.out.print(posX + " , " + posY);
   }

   public Dimension getDimension() {
      return new Dimension(tileW, tileH);
   }
}
```

Comment: Review your sentence structure and grammar before posting.

Answer (score 1):

In Tile.drawTile(), you must do the following:

```
private void drawTile() {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) gr;
    AffineTransform oldTransform = g2d.getTransform(); //new
    g2d.translate(0, 22);
    g2d.drawImage(img, posX, posY, null);
    g2d.setTransform(oldTransform); //new
    System.out.print(posX+" , "+posY);
}
```

However, there is a lot of sub-optimal code in there, but you will learn as you go along!

Comment: That is what it was showing me BEFORE i added BOTH the lines in my code. Are you sure you added both of them? Without my lines you are tranlating the drawing 22 pixels down for each tile, resulting in your screenshot.

Comment: i did . I have even copied everything again from the page and replaced the lines you said.

Comment: That's wierd. I don't have your images, so I'm just using rectangles, does this work allright? http://pastebin.com/WMCH1jc0

Comment: Great! Accepting my answer would be much appreciated :) By the way, you should really look into the recursion you have at Map.drawMap(). This function calls itself for each tile, meaning that your stack trace is already way deep!

Answer (score 1):

Don't draw directly in your JFrame nor in a paint method, nor should  you create objects and initialize them from within a paint or paintComponent method.

Why not simply display the tile images as ImageIcons held by JLabels?  The JFrame's contentPane could hold the JLabels in a GridLayout to make it super easy to do.

You'll also want to review a tutorial or two on Swing Graphics as it can get tricky (at least it was for me), and often we have to throw out a lot of preconceived assumptions when learning to do this type of coding.

Again, just to see how easy it is with JLabels (images simplified since I don't have access to your image files):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class UsersFrame2 extends JFrame {
   private static final int TILE_H = 25;
   private static final int TILE_W = 25;
   private static final String MAP_1_ST[] = { 
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0111111110011111111000000",
         "0111111110011111111000000",
         "0111111110011111111000000",
         "0111000110011100011000000",
         "0110000110011000011000000",
         "0111001110011100111000000",
         "0111101110011110111000000",
         "0111111110011111111000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000001000000000000000",
         "0000000010000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000",
         "0000000000000000000000000", };
   private ImageIcon grassIcon;
   private ImageIcon waterIcon;
   private JLabel[][] labelGrid = new JLabel[MAP_1_ST.length][MAP_1_ST[0].length()];

   public UsersFrame2() {
      loadPics();
   }

   public static void main(String s[]) {
      JFrame frame = new UsersFrame2();
      frame.setTitle("RPG");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      //frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   private void loadPics() {
      // TODO: uncomment this:
      // Image grass = new ImageIcon("/Users/olek/RESOURCES/RPG/grass.jpg").getImage();
      // Image water = new ImageIcon("/Users/olek/RESOURCES/RPG/water.jpg").getImage();
      Image grass = createImage(Color.green); // TODO: delete this
      Image water = createImage(Color.blue); // TODO: delete this
      grassIcon = new ImageIcon(grass);
      waterIcon = new ImageIcon(water);

      setLayout(new GridLayout(labelGrid.length, labelGrid[0].length));
      for (int row = 0; row < labelGrid.length; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < labelGrid[row].length; col++) {
            ImageIcon icon = MAP_1_ST[row].charAt(col) == '0' ? grassIcon
                  : waterIcon;
            labelGrid[row][col] = new JLabel(icon);
            add(labelGrid[row][col]);
         }
      }
   }

   // TODO: delete this:
   private Image createImage(Color color) {
      BufferedImage bImg = new BufferedImage(TILE_W, TILE_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g2 = bImg.createGraphics();
      g2.setBackground(color);
      g2.clearRect(0, 0, TILE_W, TILE_H);
      g2.dispose();
      return bImg;
   }

}
```

Comment: @user965675: please see edit and additional code in my answer.